# How to remove unwanted spaces in html tags using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, trim, html-entities

I have one Javascript variable. The variable is given below

```
 var str = '< table class = "buy_selection" >
 < tbody > 
 < tr >
 < th > size < / th >
 < td >
 < select id = "Specification_select" name = "Specification" >
 < option value = "014 black / white" > 014 black / white < / option >
 < option value = "100 white/v red" > 100/v red white < / option > 
 < option value = "101 white/black" > 101 white/black < / option > 
 < option value = "102 white/white" > 102/white < / option >
 < / select > 
 < / Td >
 < / tr > 
 < tr >
 < th > color < / th > 
 < td >
 < select id = "Specification_select" name = "Specification" >
 < option value = "23.0" > 23.0 < / option > 
 < option value = "23.5" > 23.5 < / option >
 < option value = "24.0" > 24.0 < / option > 24.5 
 < option value = "24.5" > < / option > 
 < option value = "25.0" > 25.0 < / option >
 < option value = "25.5" > 25.5 < / option >
 < option value = "26.0" > 26.0 < / option > 
 < option value = "26.5" > 26. 5 < / option > 
 < option value = "27.0" > 27.0 < / option > 
 < option value = "27.5" > 27.5 < / option > 
 < option value = "28.0" > 28.0 < / option >
 < option value = "28.5" > 28.5 < / option > 
 < option value = "29.0" > 29.0 < / option > 
 < option value = "30.0" > 30.0 < / option >
 < option value = "30.5" > 30.5 < / option > 
 < option value = "31.0" > 31.0 < / option > 
 < / select > 
 < / td >
 < / tr > write < tr > 
 < th > reviews 10 0 Yen discount < / th >
 < td >
 < select id = "Specification_select" name = "Specification" >,
 < option value = "review to write" > write reviews < / option >
 < option value = "write a review [100-yen discount]" > [100-yen discount] write a review < / option >
 < / select > 
 < / td > 
 < / tr > 
 < / tbody > ';
```

I need to format this table and assign into one div using Javascript or jQuery.

I have already tried `trim()` and `html_entity_decode`, but its not removed any unwanted spaces.

```
< table class = "buy_selection" >
```

How can i format variable. please advise.

Comment: If the data is available to you as is, then you can always use a good text editor to clean it up instead of cleaning it from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kinda bad at this, but this should do it

```
str = str.replace(/< /g, '<').replace(/<\/ /g, '</').replace(/ >/g, '>').replace(/\/ /g, '/')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/G6pHh/1/)

Comment: this code wont work for text with multiple spaces after the "<" at least it doesnt work in your fiddle when I add white spaces after the first "<"

Comment: @ElLocoCocoLoco I was not aware there were multiple spaces after `<`. At what line? (it wasn't intended to fix multiple spaces as this was a quick fix for OP, his example only has 1 space in between)

Comment: @ElLocoCocoLoco if you need it to remove more space, you will have to add some regex

Comment: Thanks, I just though that it will be more interesting having an example that works with one space or multiple spaces. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to make a DOM element of it, and get its HTML back ?

```
var new_table = $("<div>"+str+"</div>"); // create a new DOM DIV containing the element with the given text

str_without_spaces = new_table.html();
```

But anyway, do you really need to remove the spaces ? I mean, when you use the first line above, it creates a DOM table where all the spaces disapear (since the spaces between "<" and ">" are removed, and the spaces insides tags are removed if they are not html code).

So the easiest is to create the DOM element with `$(str);` and append it to something in your html page.